# PDF Generation in F1/D1 Azure plan with asp.net core

Tags: azure, asp.net-core

I currently facing an issue, and I want to know if one of stack people have a definitive answer for me.

I am trying to create a PDF from HTML in a F1 plan azure and I already try with **html-pdf and nodeService** and **dinktopdf**.

Both for some reason ( first because of phantomJS and second of wkhtmltopdf)

https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks

So someone can confirm that I do not have any solution ?

Comment: SelectPDF (https://selectpdf.com/pdf-library-for-net/) will run on a **basic** instance, otherwise I think you're going to have to look at calling out to an external service.

Comment: @BrendanGreen - to a bit more specific: the version that runs in Web Apps is a limited version, due to sandbox restrictions. You cannot run the full-featured version in Web Apps. That would require a vm.

Comment: @DavidMakogon are you specifically referring to the SelectPDF library?

Comment: I will already read the documentation for this library, but I understood that it only working with basic plan and above. But currently I want to convert a HTML string provided by my app.

Comment: @BrendanGreen correct.

Comment: In a basic plan dinktopdf works well

Answer (score 0):

method 1:
You can scale up your app service plan to Basic or higher using this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/Azure/app-service/web-sites-scale#scale-up-your-pricing-tier), then you can use other PDF generators.

method 2:
Please try EVOPDF for .net core in this site: http://www.evopdf.com/netcore-html-to-pdf-converter.aspx .
it installs "EVO HTML to PDF Server" in an Azure Cloud Service deployed in Microsoft Azure cloud.

it's also nothing to do with app service plan.

1. Download "HTML to PDF Converter v7.5 for .NET Core" under the Software Download section.
2. After download completes, unzip the file, and in the root of the EvoHtmlToPdf-NetCore-v7.5 folder, open Readme.txt.
3. In Readme.txt, nav to "Option 2. Running the Server in an Azure Cloud Service" -> "HTML to PDF Server Azure Web Role", follow the instructions to setup classic Cloud service. 
   Just remember one thing: in 'ServiceConfiguration.Cloud.cscfg' file, replace "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" to your storage account connection string.
4. Follow the "Testing the Server Installation" section to test if it's ok.

Comment: This is not correct. Almost all PDF generators fail to run in Web Apps, due to sandboxing and inability to work with GDI/ActiveX. You can't just run them by going to Basic or higher (that is specific to PDF generators that have additional versions specific to Web Apps, as discussed in comments, such as SelectPDF). Further: You're recommending an Azure Cloud Service (stateless web & worker role Windows VMs), a legacy Azure service.

Comment: Everything wkhtml-based runs in Web Apps Basic B1, it just doesn't run on shared S1 or F1.